# python selenium select one hidden item from dropdown list

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

I have this xml code with a dropdown box with name "tp" which I sucessfully accessed by name "tp" and click() to pull down a list of options but unable to get into "Today" with value "919" as below

```
<span id="sp_tp" class="dropdown select-container">
    <select name="tp" rel="Timeperiod:" id="cc_tp"  onchange=";" data-selenium-id="Timeperiod:">
        <option data-selenium-id="Timeperiod::925" value="925" title="Last 4 Weeks">Last 4 Weeks</option>                              
        <option data-selenium-id="Timeperiod::919" value="919" selected="selected" title="Today">Today</option>
```

I tried with name as below but failed. Can you help

```
select_Timeperiod = driver.find_element_by_name('tp')
select_Timeperiod.click()
select_Timeperiod.find_element_by_name('Today').click()
```

I also tried xpath and id also failed.

Answer (score 1):

> `select_Timeperiod.find_element_by_name('Today').click()`

For this to work, an element should have the *`name`attribute* equal to `Today`. In your case the `option` element has the `Today` text.

I would solve that using the handy [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

select_Timeperiod = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('tp'))
select_Timeperiod.select_by_visible_text("Today")
```

Comment: Good to know about the Select class!

Answer (score 0):

Alecxe has a good answer.  If your application happens to be localized, you won't want to find by visible text though.  Choosing by value would make this more robust in this situation:

```
select_Timeperiod = driver.find_element_by_name('tp')
select_Timeperiod.click()
select_Timeperiod.find_element_by_name('Today').select_by_value("919")
```

Comment: Hi alec.xe and Breaks Software, i tried both your answers without success with errors as below:

Comment: well, there shouldn't be a problem with the path.  the error indicates that the find_element_by_name('Today') didn't work.  Since it did find the select_Timeperiod element there may be a lag w/ the display of the drop down.  try adding a wait for the Today element before asking to select the value in there.

Answer (score 0):

xe and Breaks Software, i tried both your answers without success with errors as below:
1. select_Timeperiod.select_by_visible_text("Today")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select_by_visible_text'

2. select_Timeperiod.find_element_by_name('Today').select_by_value("919")
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'